# Top Questions of the Week #22

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 22 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[My computer freezes irregularly](https://superuser.com/questions/302401/my-computer-freezes-irregularly) is a good candidate because the OP has, with remarkable detail, documented all of the steps taken in trying to diagnose and fix the problem.  Indeed, it is one of the best questions I have ever seen on the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: I second this nomination

Comment: This one wins by vote, but nobody had the time/interest to write about it and it's not a particularly bloggable topic, so we're putting it off for now.